# Reference type is changed in proxy class that generated from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I know the title is little confusing, so here is the explaination:

I am trying to streaming a large file with WCF and I kind of know how to do it.

When I wrote a method say:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void sendStream(System.IO.Stream _StreamSource);
```

There, the generated proxy class insides my Client App will have the System.IO.Stream type as input parameter correctly.

But if I create another class:

```
[MessageContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Stream))]
public class MyData
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Data { get; set; }
}
```

And have the service interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void sendStream(MyData _StreamSource);
```

The stream type from MyData in my client class will be under Service Reference namespace.

i.e: MyServiceRef.Stream

Which made me cannot pass the stream to WCF.

But this doesn't happen for string and int stuff.

I wonder why, I throught Stream type is known type like string and int?

Or is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `KnownType` attribute instructs WCF to add type definitions to the service reference.  It appears that this also has the side effect of making any properties of a KnownType inside the DataContract to use the service-generated type.  (This makes sense for the normal usage of KnownType, where WCF does not otherwise know about the type.)

Did you try using the contract without declaring `Stream` as a `KnownType`?

Comment: I did try, but it doesn't work, that's why I added the KnownType to try my luck

Answer (score 1):

Stream is not serializable like int or string. So you can't use them as a property of a messagecontract.

You can, however, use streaming in wcf : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx, but this require to have the stream as the unique parameter.

Comment: But what I did above is working if I do not use auto-generated proxy class by sharing the service interface with client and using ChannelFactory. So does that means is impossbile to do it with auto-generated proxy class? (and yes, I am using streaming in wcf)

Comment: I admit I'm surprised this works with ChannelFactory... as described in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) above : `Restrictions on Streamed Transfers : Operations that occur across a streamed transport can have a contract with at most one input or output parameter. That parameter corresponds to the entire body of the message and must be a Message, a derived type of Stream, or an IXmlSerializable implementation. Having a return value for an operation is equivalent to having an output parameter.`

Comment: I am guessing that's what is mean by at most one input or output parameter is means the [MessageBody] in the above of code, since the [MessageHeader] is not the part of streaming during transfer. The streaming part should be the [MessageBody]. (And I tried to made another [MessageBody] in the code, it gives me error saying "In order to use Streams with the MessageContract programming model, the type MyData must have a single member with MessageBodyMember attribute and the member type must be Stream.")